# Android Ocr ( using cube option in Tesseract, Application crash)

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I want to use Cube option but getting error.
my code is as following.

```
   package com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class SimpleAndroidOCRActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";

    // You should have the trained data file in assets folder
    // You can get them at:
    // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
    public static final String lang = "eng";

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

    protected Button _button;
    // protected ImageView _image;
    protected EditText _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };

        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }

        // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
                // You can get them at:
                // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
                // This area needs work and optimization
                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/eng.traineddata");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
                    }
                }


                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.cube.bigrams")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.cube.bigrams");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.cube.bigrams");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.cube.bigrams");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.cube.bigrams " + e.toString());
                    }
                }


                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.cube.fold")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.cube.fold");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.cube.fold");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.cube.fold");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.cube.fold " + e.toString());
                    }
                }


                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.cube.lm")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.cube.lm");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.cube.lm");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.cube.lm");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.cube.lm " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.cube.nn")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.cube.nn");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.cube.nn");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.cube.nn");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.cube.nn " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.cube.params")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.cube.params");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.cube.params");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.cube.params");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.cube.params " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.cube.size")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.cube.size");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.cube.size");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.cube.size");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.cube.size " + e.toString());
                    }
                }


                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.cube.word-freq")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.cube.word-freq");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.cube.word-freq");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.cube.word-freq");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.cube.word-freq " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

                if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/ara.traineddata")).exists()) {
                    try {

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.traineddata");
                        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                                + "tessdata/ara.traineddata");

                        // Transfer bytes from in to out
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        //gin.close();
                        out.close();

                        Log.v(TAG, "Copied ara.traineddata");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy ara.traineddata " + e.toString());
                    }
                }


        // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
        _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

        _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    // Simple android photo capture:
    // http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

    protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

        if (resultCode == -1) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }

        // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang, TessBaseAPI.OEM_CUBE_ONLY);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

        baseApi.end();

        // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
        // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
        // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

        Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

        if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
        }

        recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

        if ( recognizedText.length() != 0 ) {
            _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
            _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
        }

        // Cycle done.
    }

    // www.Gaut.am was here
    // Thanks for reading!
}
```

My LogCat as following

```
07-29 14:04:03.028: I/Choreographer(601): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-29 14:04:03.355: D/dalvikvm(601): Added shared lib /data/data/com.project.ocrutilityv4/lib/liblept.so 0x411e7cb8
07-29 14:04:03.355: D/dalvikvm(601): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.project.ocrutilityv4/lib/libtess.so 0x411e7cb8
07-29 14:04:04.735: D/dalvikvm(601): Added shared lib /data/data/com.project.ocrutilityv4/lib/libtess.so 0x411e7cb8
07-29 14:04:06.595: A/libc(601): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 719 (AsyncTask #1)
07-29 14:04:10.515: I/Choreographer(601): Skipped 948 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-29 14:04:12.666: E/Trace(728): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-29 14:04:13.555: W/Resources(728): Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x35 "1900" a=2 r=0x7f06000f}
07-29 14:04:13.555: W/Resources(728): Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x35 "1900" a=2 r=0x7f06000f}
07-29 14:04:22.065: D/dalvikvm(728): GC_CONCURRENT freed 123K, 3% free 8331K/8519K, paused 80ms+95ms, total 352ms
07-29 14:04:22.886: I/Choreographer(728): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-29 14:04:22.945: D/gralloc_goldfish(728): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

I added following in tessdata folder But it's not helpful for me.:(

```
 ara.cube.bigrams
 ara.cube.fold
 ara.cube.lm
 ara.cube.nn
 ara.cube.params
 ara.cube.size
 ara.cube.word-freq
 ara.traineddata
```

without ocrEngineMode = TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED my application run fine.

Comment: I have already read that's conversation but that's not helpful for me.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded error in my code that's is as following.

public static final String lang = "ara";
//(not) public static final String lang = "eng";

Then above code is perfect running after adding following file into assets/tessdata folder.

```
 ara.cube.bigrams
 ara.cube.fold
 ara.cube.lm
 ara.cube.nn
 ara.cube.params
 ara.cube.size
 ara.cube.word-freq
 ara.traineddata
```

Thanks to all who's reply me and help me.:)

Comment: And I also Update my above code... if you remove above mentioned error then code will perfect run.:)

Comment: this was driving me crazy. thank you for your answer:)! unfortunately I am getting gibberish when taking a picture of a word. for example if I take a picture of البيت the result I get has many lines and many weird words not related to البيت. 
did this occur with you?

Comment: I can't find these files , please how can I download these files

Comment: I can't download these files from here 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00